# Globals.Ribbons empty on Outlook addin startup?

Tags: windows, ms-office

I'm creating a plugin for Outlook 2010 using VSTO 2010 and .NET 4. I am using the XML method to design my ribbon because I need the context-menu hooks. Unfortunately, though the ribbon is created before the Startup event handler of the addin is fired, I can't access the ribbon using `Globals.Ribbons.MyRibbon` in the handler! I have added the following in my Ribbon.cs code:

```
partial class ThisRibbonCollection : Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonReadOnlyCollection
{
  internal MyRibbon MyRibbon
  {
    get { return this.GetRibbon<MyRibbon>(); }
  }
}
```

But it seems that the RibbonReadOnlyCollection is *empty* when I try to access it from the startup event handler.

On the other hand, if I use the designer, I can access the collection with no problem. How do I add my new ribbon into the collection? I don't see any set methods or any instance of the ribbon collection that's tweakable.

Comment: Any resolution to this? I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: Nope, haven't found one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ribbons created with XML are not accessible using `Globals.Ribbons`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6008424/653462) answer.

Answer (score 0):

ThisAddIn

```
public Ribbon myRibbon;
protected override Microsoft.Office.Core.IRibbonExtensibility CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject()
            {
                Ribbon appointmentRibbon = new Ribbon();
                myRibbon = appointmentRibbon;  // save to local variable

                IRibbonExtensibility ribbonExtensibility = appointmentRibbon;
                return ribbonExtensibility;
            }
```

Comment: Have same issue, for some reason see no MyRibbon at ThisRibbonCollection class... should be autogenerated