# Is there a way to access a Ribbon (XML) at run time?

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto, ms-office, add-in

I'm working on a Word 2007 app-level add-in. So far, I haven't experienced major obstacles except for converting the add-in's Ribbon interface to XML. I have to use Ribbon XML because the feature I'm working on can only be done this way. The problem is that by switching to Ribbon XML I can no longer access the interface at run time via Globals.Ribbons. This link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb772088.aspx does a good job explaining how to access a Visual Designer Ribbon but it completely ignores the XML Ribbon case. Specifically, I need to be able to access some visual controls such as labels. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Globals.Ribbons is a VSTO designer feature, if you use RibbonXML then you don't have this feature.
What the designer actually does under the covers is it will create ribbon xml for Office, then when office makes a callback, VSTO will raise the appropriate event handler for that context (document). Because you are using RibbonXML you are bypassing the VSTO Ribbon designer support entirely (I prefer it this way, it is faster and you have more control).

With ribbon XML you will have to register a onLoad callback for your label, Office will then pass you a IRibbonControl, which will be the label, and you have limited stuff you can do. If you wanted to change the text then off the top of my head you would have to register a getText callback, then invalidate that ribbon control, which will cause the getText callback to be reevaluated.

Having more info about what you actually want to achieve would be handy =) I have a feeling my VSTO contrib project will also make your life much easier, as it gives you many of the nice Ribbon Designer features when using ribbon xml. But let me know what it is you want to do, and I can give you more info about that.

Cheers,
Jake

Comment: Hi Jake. Thanks for the answer. I actually did a lot of research since I posted this question and I arrived to the same conclusion. I was still hoping that someone found some way to access the interface from Global.Ribbons. Anyway, I actually converted my solution and now I use RibbonXML and callbacks to change labels, display information and change the visibility of certain controls.

Comment: Your response/answer Jake is much appreciated. MSDN doesn't seem to cover this anywhere. Invalidating the control worked perfectly.

Answer (score 6):

When working with Ribbon XML, I tried this but I couldn't access the Ribbon1 property from the Globals.Ribbons.. The property simple wasn't there..

However, I came up with another solution which basically had to do with a proper type cast.

In ThisAddIn.cs:

```
private Microsoft.Office.Core.IRibbonExtensibility ribbonObj;
protected override Microsoft.Office.Core.IRibbonExtensibility CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject()
{
 ribbonObj = new Ribbon1(this);
 return ribbonObj;
}

private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{ 
 // Calling the public method TEST() in Ribbon1.cs 
 //MyNameSpace is the namespace used in your project ie., your project name 
 ((MyNameSpace.Ribbon1)ribbonObj).TEST();
 // Calling the public variable flag in Ribbon1.cs  
 ((MyNameSpace.Ribbon1)ribbonObj).flag;
}
```

Comment: Your response worked like a charm in my similar case. Thank you for helping me (and probably many other readers on this very difficult issue). It was nice of you to take your time to write your solution there even probably you read the post almost a year later. Can't thank you enough for saving me at least one more day of struggle after I had already spent one full day on the issue with no luck.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on when you are trying to access Globals.ribbons.

As I recall, it won't be populated until very near the end of the start up phase of Word.

if you try and access it too early, there won't be any ribbons defined yet.

Comment: I'm trying to access the Globals.Ribbons from Application_DocumentOpen which is the function that gets called when a new document is opened. The thing is that this used to work for the Visual Designer Ribbon. However, after switching, Globals.Ribbons.Count is always 0 although the XML Ribbon is displayed.