# VSTO: Change the states of a toggle button in an own ribbon

Tags: c#, .net, vsto

I have a **VSTO Excel** application with an **own ribbon** (defined in **XML**). The ribbon also consists of a toggle button. I want to change the state of the toggle button programmatically (from "Unpressed" to "Pressed"). It seemed that via **Globals.ribbons** it is not possible to access the button. Or is it not possible to access the content of a ribbon bar programmatically, except via callback methods?

Comment: Yeah, it seems like it is not possible. Here is a similar question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5780063/is-there-a-way-to-access-a-ribbon-xml-at-run-time

Answer (score 0):

You could change what "getPressed" callback returns and then call 
`(Ribbon as IRibbonUI)?.InvalidateControl("myToggleButtonId");`, where Ribbon is what is passed into `OnRibbonLoad(object ribbon)` callback. Then "getPressed" will be called again and the toggle button will be set accordingly to the return value.