# Get customized togglebutton in outlook addin

Tags: vba, outlook, ms-office, outlook-addin, ribbonx

Hi I develop an addin for outlook where I want to add a new customized toggle button in the appointment tab. When I save the appointment I want to get the current state of the toggle button.
This is my code so far:

So the button is already created, but when I press save, I can't get the button control.
  Ribbon1.xml:

```
<tab idMso="TabAppointment">
        <group id="SalesforceGroup" label="Salesforce">
          <toggleButton id="ImportToSalesforce" size="large"
            label="Import to Salesforce" imageMso="DatabaseInsert"
            getPressed="GetPressed"
            onAction="Salesforce_Click"  />
        </group>
      </tab>
```

Ribbon1.vb:

```
Public Sub GetPressed(ByVal control As Office.IRibbonControl)
        MsgBox("test")   ' This alert only pops up when the appointment window opens
    End Sub

Public Sub Salesforce_Click(ByVal control As Office.IRibbonControl)
    MsgBox("test")    ' This alert never pops up
End Sub
```

ThisAddIn.vb:

```
Private Sub inspectors_NewInspector(ByVal Inspector As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Inspector) Handles inspectors.NewInspector
    If TypeName(Inspector.CurrentItem) = "AppointmentItem" Then
        MsgBox("event")
        oAppointmentItem = TryCast(Inspector.CurrentItem, Outlook.AppointmentItem)
        AddHandler oAppointmentItem.Write, AddressOf Item_Save
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Item_Save(ByRef Cancel As Boolean)
  'get IRibbonControl
End Sub
```

**UPDATE:**
Fixed the problem, that my onAction function never get called, because the parameter wasn't set right:
Ribbon1.vb:

```
Public Sub Salesforce_Click(ByVal control As Office.IRibbonControl, _
    ByVal isPressed As Boolean)
    MsgBox("test2")
End Sub
```

But the main question is: how to get the state of the toogle button when the user press save?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand your basic need, you need to be able to check the state of the ToggleButton "ImportToSalesforce" when an Appointment is saved. I am not sure whether you are fine with using the Ribbon ( created from the Visual Designer ) instead of Ribbon XML ( which is more flexible and needs more programming as compared to the Visual Designer created Ribbon )

When you create the Ribbon using Visual Designer(with the needed Toggle Button) , you can easily access the ribbon object from anywhere inside the Addin, using the Ribbon collection.

ThisRibbonCollection ribbons = Globals.Ribbons[Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveInspector()];
ribbons.SalesForceRibbon.toggleButton1.Checked  <-- This is what you need !

In case you really need to use the Ribbon XML, instead of Ribbon Visual Designer, please refer -
[Is there a way to access a Ribbon (XML) at run time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5780063/is-there-a-way-to-access-a-ribbon-xml-at-run-time)

Comment: There is no need to retype the answer anew, moreover copying the idea of accessing the ribbon controls at runtime.

Comment: "copying the idea of accessing the ribbon controls at runtime" can you please explain this ?

Comment: I had already described the Global.Ribbons property for accessing controls at runtime.

Comment: Thanks to both of you! I now have access to my toggle button when the user press 'Save'. The solution was to create the ribbon with the Visual Designer and not with Ribbon XML as Sanjay mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

You need to call the GetPressed function declared in the custom UI markup as a callback for the toggleButton. It should look like the following one:

```
C#: bool GetPressed(IRibbonControl control)
VBA: Sub GetPressed(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef returnValue)
C++: HRESULT GetPressed([in] IRibbonControl *pControl, [out, retval]VARIANT_BOOL *pvarfPressed)
Visual Basic: Function GetPressed(control As IRibbonControl) As Boolean
```

As you may see it returns a boolean value in which you are interested. If you don't use the parameter in the callback, just pass Nothing (null in C#).

It seems you don't understand how Ribbon callbacks are designed and should be used. I'd recommend reading the following series of articles in MSDN:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338202%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338199(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa722523(v=office.12).aspx)

Also you may find the Globals.Ribbons property helpful, see [Accessing the Ribbon at Run Time](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb772088.aspx) for more information.

Comment: Where do I have to put the function? And how do I get the current state of the button when the user save the appointment?

Comment: Where did you define the getPressend callback?

Comment: It should be - Sub GetPressed(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef returnValue)

Comment: and what do I have to write in the GetPressed function to get the state of the button when the user press 'save'?

Comment: so for clarification: The save button is not my customized button.. When the user press the 'Save and Close' button(applied by Outlook) then I want to get the state of my customized button

Comment: If the button belongs to your custom UI you should be aware of the current state. The GetPressed callback returns the value whether the button is in the pushed state or not. The second parameter passed to the GetPressed callback is the answer to the question. What value do you return to Office when it asks for the current state?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73939/discussion-between-zerone-and-eugene-astafiev).