# How can i have multiple XML Ribbon in one Add-In

Tags: c#-4.0, ms-word, vsto, ms-office, office-addins

I want to have two Ribbon XML in one Word Add-In. Ribbon1 is a button in a right click menu and Ribbon2 is a tab with other function. i try in the `CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject()` but the i just call one Ribbon Can you please help me? Thanks!!

Comment: Your problem description isn't very clear, but if I understand you correctly you're asking how to combine right-click menu customizations with Ribbon customizations? Both can be in the same Ribbon XML.

Comment: O sorry it's ( **Ribbon1** is a button in a right click menu and **Ribbon2** is a tab with other functions.) . Although I already managed to combine the XML

Comment: So you're OK, now?

Comment: oh, yes, Thank u soo. Now my problem is how to access a Ribbon (XML) at run time?.  I need enable some buttons depending on the user. I've been reading this [link]( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5780063/is-there-a-way-to-access-a-ribbon-xml-at-run-time). But i not understand. i need some kind of example.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not forum, where a discussion "meanders" from one topic to another in a "thread". The concept here is Q&A, so one question with one topic and (maybe) one or more answers. So start a new question. Describe what you have. Include a [mcve] with simple Ribbon XML and the ribbon class created for it by VSTO. Describe what you need and how you've tried it - research the concept "callbacks" for Ribbon XML, first, especially the "get" types, such as `getEnabled` or `getVisible` or even `getLabel`.

Comment: Thank u so much, sorry for  "meanders".

Comment: try https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s2/win003.htm

Answer (score 0):

You don't.  You have both in a single ribbon and selectively show and hide which items depending on context..